# how to check if two files are existing in a directory using while loop?

Tags: shell, unix

Hereby my code:

```
while [ -f  $load_extract_process ] || [ -f $Sr_details_update_process ]
do
sleep 3s
echo "mango"
done
echo "completed"
```

I want to check any one of the triggers is present. In that case, go to sleep mode, else print "completed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is missing just one character, a `!`. You want the loop to continue *until* one of the file exists, not while it exists. So the following code will work:

```
while ! [ -f /tmp/a1 ] || [ -f /tmp/a2 ]; do sleep 1; echo sleeping; done
```

Instead of the shell's `!` and `||`, you can also use parameters from within test (`[` is just an alias for `test`):

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/a1 -a ! -f /tmp/a2 ]; do sleep 1; echo sleeping; done
```

Note how `!` is now handled by test (`[`) not by the shell, and `-a` means **and**.
You decide which of the two implementations is clearer to you (in my opinion, it's the second).

Comment: your second option worked for me thanks :)
while [ -f /tmp/a1 -o  -f /tmp/a2 ]; do sleep 1; echo sleeping; done
this one worked for me as my requirement
thank you very much

Comment: I think I misunderstood what exactly you wanted the loop condition to be, but I'm happy you were able to take pieces from my answer to do exactly what you wanted to do :-)